# Restructure code from PSTCollectionView to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, pstcollectionview

I have completely removed `PSTCollectionView` from my project, at one point, I'm getting following error, `PSTCollectionViewItemTypeCell` not found. I'm aware that, I need to replace it with something available in `UICollectionView` but I haven't found it on myself.

Is anyone experienced both (`PSTCollectionView/UICollectionView`) then please suggest me an alternative for that peace of code.

This is a rare question as from iOS 6.0 and above versions – people may upgrade to `UICollectionView`smoothly. However, I'm running an old project and that needs to be completely restructured for iOS 9.0.

Please help.

Here's the problematic code:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)[super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([attributes representedElementCategory] == PSTCollectionViewItemTypeCell) {
        //some good code.
    }
    return attributes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the `PSTCollectionView` repository that [`PSTCollectionViewItemTypeCell`](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView/blob/3add712952e24bc04396b34a17ef9fee16dcd1d9/PSTCollectionView/PSTCollectionViewLayout.h#L13) is a member of the `PSTCollectionViewItemType` enum:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, PSTCollectionViewItemType) {
    PSTCollectionViewItemTypeCell,
    PSTCollectionViewItemTypeSupplementaryView,
    PSTCollectionViewItemTypeDecorationView
};
```

This is essentially the equivalent of [`UICollectionElementCategory`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@UICollectionElementCategory):

```
typedef enum {
   UICollectionElementCategoryCell,
   UICollectionElementCategorySupplementaryView,
   UICollectionElementCategoryDecorationView 
} UICollectionElementCategory;
```

It should be simply a case of replacing one for the other:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)[super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([attributes representedElementCategory] == UICollectionElementCategoryCell) {
        //some good code.
    }
    return attributes;
}
```